# F# Xamarin.IOS Removing Spcific Nuget Package Breaks Build

Tags: f#, xamarin.ios, monogame

I am building a class library targeting Xamarin.IOS with F#. I would like to remove a dependency on the package `FsEssentials_jhbertra`, as it is not used and obsolete.

However, when I remove the package, it seems that the dependency on `FSharp.Core` breaks, as I get several new compiler errors saying things like `float` and `List` cannot be found.

The current `master` of this repo builds https://github.com/jhbertra/FsGame But not when removing the indicated package from `FsGame.iOS`

Comment: Some other package has a dependency on an older version of `FSharp.Core`. The package you just removed was pulling the version up, but now it's back down. To fix, add an explicit dependency on `FSharp.Core` of appropriate version.